# Automated SCSS > CSS > SFTP upon saving in SublimeText3

Tags: sass, sublimetext3

I'm using ST3's SFTP plugin and have it configured to `upload_on_save`.  I'd like to have a way to setup my workflow in such a way that once I save changes on a *.scss* file it is automatically compiled and the resulting *.css* is automatically uploaded to the server.

So far I can automatically compile using cli's `sass --watch` but resulting *.css* is not automatically uploaded.  I can also automatically upload when saving the *.css* file from within ST3.  I just don't see how to join the complete SCSS > CSS > SFTP process as an automated task.

EDIT: There is a solution posted over 2 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491009/sublime-sftp-upload-compiled-css-when-sass-file-saved?rq=1).  Hopefully there is something new around.

Comment: Did you try the solutions suggested in the linked question? If so, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: I looked around for that solution before posting this question.  It was suggested once I posted. That's why I added the edit.  I've been using it for a couple of hours now and so far is exactly what I needed.  I'm just curious if a better solution has been discovered in the past two and a half years.

Comment: The solution presented there is quite straightforward and robust, so I'm not quite sure what you mean by a "better solution". I've marked this question as a duplicate, because the answer to the other question is working for you. Feel free to [search Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search) for other packages, but I doubt you'll find anything.